# VSCode tab-less editor background

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, themes

How do I change what is shown in the space normally occupied by the `editor` when there are no open tabs? I mean the space with the *gray-er* blue and the VSCode icon, in the attached screenshot

It should appear somewhere in the [Theme reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) but I'm failing to find it.

Edit: I was expecting a var like `editor.emptyStateBackground`, being editor and background the main keywords, but there is nothing in the reference that allows to update this using any of those keywords.

[image]

Comment: you want to customize the color or the content, does the color change if you switch theme? If yes you can  customize the color

Comment: it is always easier to drink coffee and let somebody else try a few theme color names to find the correct name, maybe max 10 will be needed to try, other names can be discarded (like inputbox colors)